# Regex to match swedish words but not numbers

Tags: python, regex

So I have made a regex (in Python) that currently matches all words but ignores special characters.

```
/([\wåäöÅÄÖ]+)/g
```

However, it also matches numbers. How can I make it so that it does not match numbers?

Comment: TIP : **\w** flag is Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]

Comment: Regular expressions alone are unsuitable for this task in the general case. The solutions here will still fail on e.g. *TV-program* or *idé* but more generally, you cannot tell if a matching fragment is part of a URL, an email address etc or actually a word. Systems for linguistic analysis use a language-specific tokenizer but these still achieve well below 100% on real, live, human free-form prose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\w` character class is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

So maybe:

```
[åäöÅÄÖA-Za-z_]+
```

will be better choice

Comment: Did not know that about \w! Thank you very much.

Comment: `\w` isn't a "flag" but a character class and its content changes depending of the context (unicode or not). By default in python 2.7 it contains only `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, but with the unicode flag (`re.U`) or by default in Python 3 it contains also accented letters, letters and digits from other alphabets.